# Troubleshoot DBMail in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

On a SQL Server 2005 machine, I have DBMail setup and correctly configured. I am able to use "Notify Operator" and EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail to queue emails.

But the problem is the queued mails never go through. I see 10 emails in the queue when I query

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems
```

But if I **restart** the SQL Server service, all mails go through and I receive emails in my inbox.

So far this is the only pattern I could find.

So my question is: is there a way to troubleshoot DBmail? I read some steps on MSDN, but they are not of much help. Any URLs to articles that could help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for all your comments. I found the root of the problem.

**Sql Agent >> Properties >> Alert System (tab) >> Enable Mail profile (check)** 
And select appropriate mail system and add a mail profile.

[MSDN Link for DB Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186358%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

This took care of the problem.

When I look at Sql Agent Logs it had a log entry as "Unable to start mail session (reason: no mail profile defined)". Using this key word, I was able to search online and get some help.

Comment: Everything is now fine. :-)

Comment: Yes it seems like it.

Answer (score 8):

Have you start the service broker on MSDB ? You need the service broker on to be able to process mail queue.

Read this post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002/how-do-i-get-dbmail-to-process-items-from-the-queue-for-sql-server-2005).
An other link that may help you is [how to troubleshoot a queue in sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190630.aspx).
You can also use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166086.aspx) to get your service broker up and running on MSDB.

Hope that those links may help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestions and post my results.

Comment: yes, I did try all of those. Everything returned as STARTED or running okay. Looks like the problem is with Sql Agent Alert System settings. See below